# Is this argument correct: "if $a,b$ are real numbers and if we assume that $a+b$ is algebraic, then so it is $a-b$ "?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, logic, transcendental-numbers

Is the similar argument presented in the proof below correct: " if $\ln \Gamma(z) + \ln \Gamma(1-z)$ is algebraic for some rational not integer $z$ , then, so it's their difference, $\ln \Gamma(z) - \ln \Gamma(1-z)$ " ?

In the proof below they use distinct values for $x$, but let's keep just one variable $z$.

[image]

The question here is: if $a,b$ are real numbers and if we assume that the sum $a+b$ is algebraic, then so it is $a-b$. If both $a,b \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ then this is true. And there is exceptions like the example commented below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not necessarily true. Take $a=\pi$ and $b=-\pi$ for instance.

**Edit**

In response to the proof you added to the question, here is your error: They have not claimed that if $a+b$ is algebraic then $a-b$ is algebraic. They have used the fact that if $a$ and $b$ are both algebraic, then $a-b$ is algebraic, which *is* true.

Comment: Are cases like this the only exception? If so, in the proof that I read is correct to state "If $ \zeta(5)+\zeta(7)$ is algebraic, then, so is their difference..."

Comment: @Pinteco I don't know... there could easily be a justification in this instance. Instead of saying "I read a proof", give a reference to the proof. Or at least give a full description of the argument rather than something vague like 'it uses an argument similar to...' (but a reference is easier if it is available).

Comment: @Pinteco But if it is purporting to be proof that $\zeta(5)+\zeta(7)$ is transcendental then it is likely to be wrong cause this is an open problem.

Comment: The $\zeta$ was just an example. I updated the question with the proof that I mentioned.

Comment: @Pinteco Thank you for adding that. You have misinterpreted the argument. See my edit.

Comment: @Pinteco Let $x$ and $y$ be any two numbers. Then $x=a+b$ and $y=a-b$ where $a=(x+y)/2$ and $b=(x-y)/2$. So your "argument" saying that "if $a+b$ is transcendental then $a-b$ is transcendental" would mean that "if $x$ is transcendental then $y$ is transcendental", where $x$ and $y$ are any two numbers.